# Find method inside list

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my list

```
public string state { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public Point p1 { get; set; }
public Point p2 { get; set; }
public List<Explorer> line = new List<Explorer>();
public List<Explorer> rectangle = new List<Explorer>();
public List<Explorer> ellipse = new List<Explorer>();
```

this is my adding elements to list code

```
line.Add(new Explorer
            {
                state = "AAAA",
                city = "BBB",
                p1 = start,
                p2 = end
            });
```

relevant to the values of state and city i need to find the points of their location .

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. are these are class members?

Comment: Yes these are class members . The class name is Explorer

Comment: What needs to be achieved? not clear ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Points of their location? You mean map coordinates?

Comment: Do you want to filter  the _line_ (List<Explorer>) based on state and/or city values and select p1 / p2 ? If yes, then use simple LINQ where filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to filter your list/retrieve the item you want:

using [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb534803.aspx)

```
line.Where(e => e.state == "AAAA" && e.city == "BBB")
```

using [Single/SingleOrDefault/First/FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb155325.aspx)

```
line.SingleOrDefault(e => e.state == "AAAA" && e.city == "BBB")
```

If you are only interested in the points, you can use a [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) projection

```
var points = line.Where(e => e.state == "AAAA" && e.city == "BBB")
                    .Select(e=>Tuple.Create(e.p1, e.p2))
                    .Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
  line.Where(l=>l.state == "whatever" && l.city == "whatever").
       Select(p=> new() { point1 = p.p1, point2 = p.p2 }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have List of Explorer class as follows,

```
List<Explorer> myList;

var result = myList.SingleOrDefault(d=> d.state="somthing" && d.city="Soemthing");

// access result.points here.
```